# Should I organize my website with subdirectories?

Tags: web, organization

I use a static website generator to create my website. Currently I have all pages to be stored under the root directory. (mywebsite.com/webpage.html) Is there a technical reason why I should organize my pages in a sub-directory (category, date, etc)? These articles are tagged and organized internally . But if I start to organize in sub-directories then I have to specify them when I link pages to one another. I like the flexibility of being able to change organization anytime in the future without breaking the internal links, but I wasn't sure if my current structure will cause a problem when I generate thousands of pages this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't *necessarily* cause a programatic problem, as far as I know. However, it seems that it would be a nightmare in organization.

To me, the small pain of specifying sub-directories is well worth the added organization. It's worth nothing that a bit of consistency in naming conventions for your directories will make it *really* easy to keep up with what is where.